# How to do Android licensing checks from a ListActivity

Tags: android

Our application launches ListActivity that displays two menu options with launch a football game and a baseball game.  We are trying to implement licensing and we are having troubles figuring out how to get it working.  Two things are happening here: we are failing to bind to the licensing service (Unable to start service Intent act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService in logcat) and we are unable to see any of the status messages.  Here is our Launcher code:

```
public class Launcher extends ListActivity {

    private MenuAdapter mListAdapter;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private TextView mStatusText;
    // protected Button mCheckLicenseButton;

    private LicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;
    private LicenseChecker mChecker;

    private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "blah";
    private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] { 15, -43, -69, 107, 104,
            -111, -105, -76, -18, -24, 62, 118, 45, 67, -89, 70, 79, 123, -3,
            13 };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.launcher_menu);

        mStatusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
                Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();

        mChecker = new LicenseChecker(this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
                new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), android_id)),
                BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
        doCheck();
        // We want to see the license check and then launch the menuadapter.
        // mListAdapter = new MenuAdapter(this);
        // this.setListAdapter(mListAdapter);

    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // We have only one dialog.
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(
                R.string.unlicensed_dialog_title).setMessage(
                R.string.unlicensed_dialog_body).setPositiveButton(
                R.string.buy_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent marketIntent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri
                                        .parse("http://market.android.com/details?id="
                                                + getPackageName()));
                        startActivity(marketIntent);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.quit_button,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }).create();
    }

    private void doCheck() {
        // mCheckLicenseButton.setEnabled(false);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        mStatusText.setText(R.string.checking_license);
        mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
    }

    private void displayResult(final String result) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mStatusText.setText(result);
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                // mCheckLicenseButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
        public void allow() {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            // Should allow user access.
            displayResult(getString(R.string.allow));
            // If allowed we should display our menu options
            // mListAdapter = new MenuAdapter(this);
            // this.setListAdapter(mListAdapter);
        }

        public void dontAllow() {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }
            displayResult(getString(R.string.dont_allow));
            // Should not allow access. In most cases, the app should assume
            // the user has access unless it encounters this. If it does,
            // the app should inform the user of their unlicensed ways
            // and then either shut down the app or limit the user to a
            // restricted set of features.
            // In our case, we are failing to bind to the licensing service, so showDialog will always display.
            // Temporarily disable it till we get this working.
            // showDialog(0);
        }

        public void applicationError(ApplicationErrorCode errorCode) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            String result = String.format(
                    getString(R.string.application_error), errorCode);
            displayResult(result);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mChecker.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
        Activity act = (Activity) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        this.startActivity(new Intent(this, act.Class));
    }

}
```

All the examples show how to work with an Activity, not a list activity, and this is what is throwing us off.  I'm thinking we need to create a MainActivity which extends Activity that does the check then call the ListActivity if the check is successful.  Does that sound like the correct approach?

As for failing to bind to the licensing service, this could be network related.  We are testing on a Google API lvl 9 emulator, but we don't get the same failure to bind on the Nexus One or Galaxy Tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As for failing to bind to the licensing service, this could be network related. We are testing on a Google API lvl 9 emulator, but we don't get the same failure to bind on the Nexus One or Galaxy Tab.

This is actually just an issue with Gingerbread in the emulator. The bug is reported here:
http://code.google.com/p/marketlicensing/issues/detail?id=27&q=could%20not%20bind%20to%20service

You'll need to test LVL on 2.2 in the emulator.

Comment: Thanks, we have it sorted now.  We put a license checker or splash screen activity in front of our Launcher.